# SLR(1) parser with epsilon

Tags: parsing, grammar

let's suppose I have the following grammar:

**E --> TX**

**T --> (E) | int Y**

**X --> + E | ε**

**Y --> * T | ε**

Building the item sets I get a state like this one:

**T --> int . Y**

**Y --> . * T**

**Y --> .**

This state is adequate or not? That is, the grammar is SLR(1) or not?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes the entries specified by you in the state absolutely correct.

```
  T->int.Y
  Y->.*T
  Y->.
```

This is the 5th state in the DFA created for SLR(1) parser for given grammar.

Confusion may have arise in `Y->Ɛ` . When you place a dot in the augmented productions for example `S->A.B` it means that A is completed and B is yet to be completed (by completion here means progress in parsing) . Similarly if you write `Y->.Ɛ` , it means Ɛ is yet to be over, but we also know that Ɛ is null string i.e nothing therefore `Y->.Ɛ` is interpreted as `Y->.`

I created the DFA (13 states) for this grammar and found that the **given grammar is SLR(1) as there is no Reduce-Reduce or Shift-Reduce conflict**.

Answer (score 1):

you have to construct the FOLLOW sets and see if FOLLOW(Y) contains int or *. if that was the case there'd be a shift/reduce conflict and the grammar wouldn't be SLR(1).
check all the states and if none has conflicts the grammar is SLR(1).